Is it possible to augment input components for `WKWebView`?
We are working on an iOS app. It is built on Capacitor, but I have generalized my question, so it may be irrelevant.
The app uses a WKWebView to show an HTML form. In that form, there is an input element with type="month" and min/max attributes.
In case you are not familiar with HTML, type="month", despite it's name, is actually a year-month picker.
For example:
<input type="month" min="2024-07"/>

On iOS, 13.4+ it shows a native UIDatePicker with datePickerMode = .yearAndMonth and datePickerStyle = .wheels. However, it does not support the min and max attributes.
Is there a way to either augment the UIDatePicker that WKWebView shows for this HTML element or completely replace it? The goal being, of course, to support the min and max attributes by parsing their values and setting minimumDate and maximumDate, respectively?

I can imagine some Javascript ping/pong where you call iOS on field activation, show the picker natively and sends picker results to the WebView, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. What about web-side validation with the field just turning red in case of wrong input, or just implement custom picker, easiest option - 2 separate option pickers for month and year and refilter of available month options on year pick
